# Rails Cocoon Nested with Proc running slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I have a nested Invoice form for a model structure that has looked like this:

```
Invoice has_many Insurance::Policies
Insurance::Policy has_one Insurance::Carrier
```

The user is able to create many Insurance Policies that can each have an Insurance Carrier because I use the following Cocoon link:

```
 = link_to_add_association 'Add Insurance Policy', f, :invoice_insurance_policies, partial: "insurance/policies/nested_fields", wrap_object: Proc.new { |policy| policy.build_insurance_carrier; policy }
```

(note the Proc.new where I build the carrier.)

All of this works fine.

However, I am now in the process of nesting this relationship further to something like this:

```
Invoice has_many Insurance::Policies
Insurance::Policy has_one Insurance::Carrier
Insurance::Carrier has_one Settings
```

To be clear, I am now allowing the user to not only create a carrier, but also create the settings for that new carrier.  This can be accomplished easily by adjusting the cocoon link like so:

```
= link_to_add_association 'Add Insurance Policy', f, :invoice_insurance_policies, partial: "insurance/policies/nested_fields", wrap_object: Proc.new { |policy| policy.build_models; policy }
```

And defining a 'build_models' function within the Insurance::Policy model like so:

```
class Insurance::Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
  def build_models
    carrier = self.build_insurance_carrier
    carrier.build_insurance_carrier_settings
  end
end
```

Again, doing so works, allowing me to render the necessary carrier and nested settings fields on the form. However, building these additional attribute fields slows down my form significantly.  Clicking the link_to_add_association now causes the form to freeze for about 5-6 seconds before rendering the new fields.

1. Has anyone else come across this issue?
2. Is there an easy way to solve it while keeping the user experience the same?